# .NET - get rows from a MS Access DB with DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I have a MS Access database I am trying to access in C# using a DataSet.  However, while it can get the table's columns, it doesn't see any of its rows.

Here is the code:

```
    private void Button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder();

        DataTable TheTable = DataSet_TheData.TheTable;

        DataColumnCollection Cols = TheTable.Columns;

        DataTableReader Rows = TheTable.CreateDataReader();
        while (Rows.Read())
        {
            long Id = Rows.GetInt64(0);
            DateTime StartTime = Rows.GetDateTime(3);
            S.AppendLine(Id.ToString() + " - " + StartTime.ToString("M/d h:mm tt"));
        }
        S.AppendLine("Finished reading data");

        Text_Output.Text = S.ToString();
    }
```

DataSet_TheTable is a DataSet pointing to an Access database defined in design.
Text_Output is a TextBox.

The table contains five rows.
However, Rows.Read always returns false.
Also, if I try to access DataSet_TheData.TheTable.Rows before the loop, it shows zero rows.
Cols is populated correctly from the Access table, so it's not a case of it not being able to find the table.

Replacing "TheTable.CreateDataReader()" with "new DataTableReader(TheTable)" does not work either.

How do I get the code to find the rows in the table?

Comment: The dataset doesn't get populated in this method.  Can you show the code where you populate the dataset?  Does it ever get called?

Comment: Do you need to get a single table from the MS Access database or are you getting multiple tables and then iterating on the data (i.e. in POCOs)?

Comment: squillman - the dataset itself (DataSet_TheTable) is a design-side object.  TheTable can be found because TheTable.Columns is populated.  /  Kane - there is only one table in the database, named TheTable.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through the rows of a DataTable in c# you just need to do:

```
foreach (DataRow myRow in DataSet_TheData.Tables[0].Rows) {
    //Work with myRow here.
}
```

This will loop through the 5 rows in the DataTable returned to you.

Then, on each row you just access the value of a column for a specific row by using:

```
myRow["myColumnName"]
```

---

If you want to do this programatically for each row:

```
foreach (DataRow myRow in DataSet_TheData.Tables[0].Rows) {
    foreach (DataColumn myCol in DataSet_TheData.Tables[0].Columns) {
       //Use myRow[myCol] here
    }
}
```

Comment: DataSet_TheData.Tables[0].Rows is still empty.  Note that DataSet_TheData.Tables[0] does find the database's one table, but Rows is empty.  Is there a DataSet equivalent to OracleCommand that I need to be using?

Comment: If Rows is empty then your DataSet is not being populated with any data, can you verify that the query you wrote to populate this DataSet is returning what you expect?  Are you still calling Rows.Read() ? You should not create a CreateDataReader() or call that method if you just loop through the rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Visual Studio doesn't so much as link to the existing Access Database as make an internal empty copy of its tables, which is why the columns showed up but the rows did not.  When I added this code, the table data was populated:

```
TestAccessDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TheTableTableAdapter A =
     new TestAccessDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TheTableTableAdapter();
A.Fill(TheDataSet.TheTable);
```

Boy, that was intuitive...